# Sequelize does not create hasMany associations but foreign keys defined in DB

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

Altough it seems my associations defined in the database when I call create on my `manufacturer` model associations does not create.

These are my associated models.

```
ManufacturerText.associate = function (models) {
    models.manufacturer_text.belongsTo(models.language, {
      as: 'language'
    });
    models.manufacturer_text.belongsTo(models.manufacturer, {
      as: 'manufacturer'
    });
  };

  ManufacturerVideo.associate = function (models) {
    models.manufacturer_video.belongsTo(models.language, {
      as: 'language'
    });
    models.manufacturer_video.belongsTo(models.video_type, {
      as: 'video_type'
    });
    models.manufacturer_video.belongsTo(models.manufacturer, {
      as: 'manufacturer'
    });
  }
```

And this is the main model:
 ```

```
  Manufacturer.associate = function(models) {

// models
    models.manufacturer.hasMany(models.manufacturer_text, {foreignKey:'manufacturer_id', as: 'manufacturer_translations' });
    models.manufacturer.hasMany(models.manufacturer_video, {foreignKey:'manufacturer_id', as: 'manufacturer_videos' });
    models.manufacturer.hasMany(models.inspiration_image, {foreignKey:'manufacturer_id', as: 'inspirations' });

    models.manufacturer.belongsTo(models.file, {as: 'image'});
    models.manufacturer.belongsTo(models.file, {as: 'header_image'});

  };
```

none of the two associations above work.

When I inspect DB with MySQL Workbench it seems associations defined properly.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem caused by the input.

When you send `id` attribute even doesn't matter if its `null`, sequelize do not understand that it is an `INSERT`

I was sending a record like below;

```
{
  delivery_days: 10,
  image_id: 4,
  { id: null, url: 'http://url', ... }
}
```